# Create a Network based on a specific string column inside dataframe

Tags: pandas, list, graph, networkx, removing-whitespace

I have a data frame like this picture below:

[image]

But I have some troubles when I want to create this network.
I used this code:

```
G = nx.complete_graph(df.Members)
list(G.edges())
```

But I got error.
My question is how I can create this network based on this type of data. I should mention that each group is a complete graph and I want to assemble these groups into one. Moreover, I have some white space which leads to some duplicated nodes.

Comment: Do you need to draw the graph in such a pretty way or is your goal just to build a graph object with the data?  I ask because these are two very different questions with very different levels of difficulty.

Comment: Also, is your goal to learn how to do this yourself or to solve the problem as fast as possible and move on?

Comment: But If you can solve it based on your way, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plotting this with your formatting is at least another SO question by itself, so I stuck with parsing the data roughly as you showed it, generating a graph, and doing a crude plot.  This is the result of the code block below:

[image: shapes_graph]

All I did from a plot formatting perspective was

1. include node labels
2. fix the positions of nodes B, C, F, and J
3. fiddle with `nx.spring_layout()` parameters a bit to make the plot more recognizable.

```
import pandas as pd
import networkx as nx


d = {'Group Name': {1: 'Alpha', 2: 'Beta', 3: 'Gamma', 4: 'Omega'}, 'Members': {1: 'A, B, C', 2: 'C, D, E, F', 3: 'F, G, H, I, J', 4: 'J, K, L,M,N, O'}, 'Weight': {1: 'W1', 2: 'W2', 3: 'W3', 4: 'W4'}}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d)

subgraphs = []
for record in df.to_records():
    nodes = [node.strip() for node in record[2].split(",")]
    subgraph = nx.complete_graph(nodes)
    nx.set_edge_attributes(subgraph, record[3], name='Weight')
    subgraphs.append(subgraph)

G = nx.compose_all(subgraphs)

node_types = {'A': 1, 'B': 1, 'C':2, 'D': 1, 'E': 2, 'F': 1, 'G': 1, 'H': 1, 'I': 2, 'J': 2, 'K': 1, 'L': 1, 'M': 2, 'N': 1, 'O': 1}
nx.set_node_attributes(G, node_types, name='Type')

pos_fixed = {'B': (1, 0),
             'C': (2, 0),
             'F': (3, 0),
             'J': (4, 0),
             'K': (5, 0)}

pos = nx.spring_layout(G, k=1.25, pos=pos_fixed, fixed=pos_fixed.keys(), seed=42)

nx.draw(G, pos, with_labels=True)
```

Comment: thanks, is it possible to add node type and edge weight to that for-loop to append those data to the final graph?

Comment: @Hadi I updated the answer to reflect your feedback.  The edge weights can be passed through while iterating over each subgraph.  Since the node types are in their own data structure, I just added them all collectively after building the graph.  For future questions involving supplying tabular data or dataframes, it's definitely worth reading [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples).